# How can I loop through features in layers to create an individual geodesic viewshed raster for each feature?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor, viewshed

**What I have:**

- 1/3 Arc Second DEM for the extent of my AOI
- Feature class containing ~16 observers with fields for 'observer_offset,' 'outer_radius,' 'horizontal start angle,' and 'horizontal end angle'

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

- Create an individual single-band geodesic viewshed for each individual observer in the feature class in tif format.

**What I am attempting to use:**

- Viewshed2() in ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3

**Code I am attempting to write:**

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *


# set local variables
inRaster = r"phase_2\phase_2_dem"
inObservers = r"C:\Users\Austin\OneDrive\Documents\SynthosGIS\Geolinks\geolinks_fullrun\geolinks_fullrun\geolinks_fullrun.gdb\test_test_test"
var = None
analysisType = "FREQUENCY"
verticalError = "0 meters"
outAnalysisRelationTable = None
refractCoeff = 0.13
surfaceOffset = "0 meters"
observerElevation = None
observerOffset = "observer_off"
innerRadius = None
innerIs3D = "GROUND"
outerRadius = "Tower_Range_"
outerIs3D = "GROUND"
horizStartAngle = "hor_start_angle"
horizEndAngle = "hor_end_angle"
vertUpperAngle = 90
vertLowerAngle = -90
analysisMethod = "ALL_SIGHTLINES"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inObservers, ['Account_Name']) as vwshd_itterator:
    for row in vwshd_itterator:
        account = str(row[0])
        query = f"Account_Name = '{account}'"
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inObservers, "NEW_SELECTION", query)
            
        out_raster = arcpy.sa.Viewshed2(inRaster, inObservers, var, analysisType,
                         verticalError, outAnalysisRelationTable, refractCoeff,
                         surfaceOffset, observerElevation, observerOffset,
                         innerRadius, innerIs3D, outerRadius, outerIs3D,
                         horizStartAngle, horizEndAngle, vertUpperAngle,
                         vertLowerAngle, analysisMethod)
        out_raster.save(r"C:\Users\Austin\OneDrive\Documents\SynthosGIS\Geolinks\geolinks_fullrun\geolinks_fullrun\vwshd_" + account + ".tif")
```

**What I Need:**

- This is the first time that I have used both the Viewshed2 script and the DA SearchCursor function. I am not sure if I have integrated the two functions correctly, or what I will need to do make it run. As I type, I won't be able to try out any scripts for a couple days as I am away from my workstation. Any input to this script, so that I can hit the ground running when I get back?

**Update 1: RESOLVED**

- I have updated the code to what is currently showing. I am currently running into an issue with the query for the selection in the for loop. Am I implementing the f-string incorrectly?

**Update 2: UNRESOLVED**

- I have achieved a function that will run. However, the select by attribute function does not appear to be looping through features individually. Instead it selects all features on the layer at once and is creating a separately named file reprocessing the same viewshed over and over again.

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with `input_feature_class` inside the loop at all.

Comment: @Vince, I edited to use the appropriate variable. I had been working between a couple example scripts to learn the syntax in this and completely just missed that I was using the wrong variable.

Comment: A DA Cursor doesn't change the selection environment, and altering the selection environment in the middle of cursor use is fraught, at best. Instead, grab the OIDs as a cursor-generated list outside the loop, then use SelectByAttribute using OID inside the loop.

Comment: So, I would use the search cursor to to .append() the OID to a new empty list, then use something like this?

        '''
        for s in new_list:
             arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('inObservers', 'NEW_SELECTION', where 'OID' == s
                    Viewshed2()
'''

Comment: Well, something like, `oidList = [r[0] for arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inObservers, ['OID@'])]`... The OID column is different by source datatype, so it might be `""""FID" = {:d}""".format(s)`

Comment: That makes sense! My comment box will absolutely not let me mark in code for some reason. But did the loop for the selection and view shed look correct?

Comment: Single backticks work in body and comment for code formatting

Comment: `query = f'Account_Name = {account]'
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("pts", "NEW_SELECTION", query)`

Breaking on the selection query, error 000358 'invalid expression.' Might have a suggestion on this?

Comment: I have edited the original post to reflect my current status on this as well if needing further context.

Comment: If it's a string, you need to add apostrophes around the variable

Comment: I'm a little lost in that... `query = f'Account_Name = {account}'` sets the string field "Account_Name" should equal "{account}" which is already defined as a string. Where should I be modifying this to address the syntax issue?

Comment: `query = f"Account_Name = '{account}'"` SQL literals must have quotes

Comment: I have once again updated the code block on the main post. The function runs, but the selection loop selects ALL features instead of one at a time. Therefore processing the same viewshed repeatedly.

Comment: You missed the part in  comment #3 (and #5) where the list of keys is extracted **before** looping to prevent corrupting the cursor by changing the selected features.

Comment: This does not seem to resolve the issue in the selection loop.  Specifically, as written above, the tool selects feature 1, then runs the viewshed with no consideration for the selection. Then on the second loop, it selects features 1 and 2, then runs the viewshed again with no reference to the selection. This is the same using a for loop `for x in list:` or running the loop under the search cursor.

Comment: Disregard. The viewshed2 script was causing individual observer layers to be created on each loop due to some issue with the original "inObservers" feature layer. Adding CreateFeatureLayer outside of the loop and then using this in the viewshed2 parameters fixed the issue. I'll post a final solution as an answer. If you see any ways to improve the script, could you please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a great deal of back and forth with Vince on throwing this together, I am happy to say I have reached a functional final result. The below successfully translates my feature class into a functional feature layer, the iterates over that layer and stores an attribute field into a list to use as selection criteria to loop the viewshed2 tool through on each individual feature.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *


# set local variables
inRaster = r"phase_2\phase_2_dem"
inObservers = r"C:\Users\Austin\OneDrive\Documents\SynthosGIS\Geolinks\geolinks_fullrun\geolinks_fullrun\geolinks_fullrun.gdb\fc_phase_2_towers"
var = None
analysisType = "FREQUENCY"
verticalError = "0 meters"
outAnalysisRelationTable = None
refractCoeff = 0.13
surfaceOffset = "0 meters"
observerElevation = None
observerOffset = "observer_off"
innerRadius = None
innerIs3D = "GROUND"
outerRadius = "Tower_Range_"
outerIs3D = "GROUND"
horizStartAngle = "hor_start_angle"
horizEndAngle = "hor_end_angle"
vertUpperAngle = 90
vertLowerAngle = -90
analysisMethod = "ALL_SIGHTLINES"
inLayer = 'pts'

arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(inObservers, inLayer)

account = [str(row[0]) for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inLayer, ['Account_Name'])]
print(account)

for a in account:
    query = f"Account_Name = '{a}'"
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inLayer, "NEW_SELECTION", query)
    out_raster = Viewshed2(inRaster, inLayer, var, analysisType,
                         verticalError, outAnalysisRelationTable, refractCoeff,
                         surfaceOffset, observerElevation, observerOffset,
                         innerRadius, innerIs3D, outerRadius, outerIs3D,
                         horizStartAngle, horizEndAngle, vertUpperAngle,
                         vertLowerAngle, analysisMethod)

    out_raster.save(r"C:\Users\Austin\OneDrive\Documents\SynthosGIS\Geolinks\geolinks_fullrun\test_itterate\vwshd_" + str(a) + ".tif")
    print('completed ' + str(a))
```